# How do I display CSV data in a html file without hosting on a server

Tags: html, csv

I know there are other answers to this problem and I have tried them all. Is it possible to only use html to show csv data. So far the only solutions I can find are not working
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> The message you want to send is <i><big><b>{{ message }}</b></big></i></h1>
    <h1>You will send the message to these people</h1>


    #I want to show the csv file here



    <button> <a href="/sendmessage/">Send message to everyone in the list</a></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does 'without hosting' mean? Where will the csv file be located? Do you just want to paste the data manually? If it is the last one, put it in the pre tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title asks about no server, and the question asks about html only. So, to answer both:

1. With HTML only you cannot get anything from anywhere. You need to add it manually.
2. Without a connection to a server, you would have to update the code manually every time the CSV file changes. If the CSV is hosted somewhere else, you can fetch using JavaScript. If the CSV is yours, you need to host it somewhere i.e. a server, to be able to access it.